# Needing to restart WampServer frequently

Tags: internet-explorer, wampserver

I am using WampServer with PHP 5.4.12 on Windows 7 and I am facing problem that WampServer very frequently (Not every time) stop working i.e., they keep loading and never open when I try to open localhost webpages on different browsers especially on IE. I need to restart the service in order to get it running again.

Do you experience this kind of problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: What version of WAMPSever have you got installed?

Comment: @RiggsFolly WampServer 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try adding these 2 parameters to your `httpd.conf` file. As per the comments it can solve these problems on a windows system that may have some odd issues with the network card and its drivers.

```
# AcceptFilter: On Windows, none uses accept() rather than AcceptEx() and
# will not recycle sockets between connections. This is useful for network
# adapters with broken driver support, as well as some virtual network
# providers such as vpn drivers, or spam, virus or spyware filters.
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

Just before this line

```
# Supplemental configuration
```